# What is this thin steel wire connected to the ungrounded side of a two-wire cable in my basement ceiling?

Tags: wiring, hvac, basement

I recently purchased a home (built in the 50s, northern USA) and the man who previously lived there definitely did some DIY work around the house. I found a mess of (seemingly disconnected) wiring that connects to a thin steel cable in my basement ceiling, and I'd like to know what it is / was.

Within an air duct, there's a long pair of wires, perhaps 18 awg, orange and white. They go through some holes in the duct, and the orange wraps around a pipe, I assume to ground it. The white one is soldered to what looks like a thin steel cable that runs all throughout the basement. It is installed much more neatly, and I assume was professionally installed to once serve a useful purpose.

I'd like to know what the thin steel cable is, what it was originally for, and anything I should know when I pull out the orange and white wiring and disconnect them from it.

[image: Here's the orange and white wiring seen in the vent]

[image: This is the thin steel cable it connects to]

[image: Here's how the thin steel cable terminates]

Comment: I removed the "feel free to speculate" portion because that invites opinion and opinion-based questions are explicitly off topic.

Comment: Just for what it's worth: there's a bare steel wire running from basement to attic in my house because I left it there to make pulling new cables easier in the future. But mine isn't secured anywhere near as neatly as this one.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Appears most likely to be an old long-wire Radio Antenna. Likely run through the duct to get to where the receiver was. Unlikely to have been a transmitting antenna.

Typical of "crystal" radio sets, and many shortwave receivers. *More modern "crystal" designs generally use a commercial diode rather than a crystal acting as a diode. Usually shorthanded to crystal as they are otherwise quite similar.*

Comment: the crystal part seems irrelevant

Comment: Given it's by far the most common sort of radio attached to this sort of antenna, it's relevant.

Answer (score 4):

It looks like simple half of the bipolar antenna (horizontal antenna) used in CB radio communication.

It operates in 27 Mhz range.

Since its total length is 11+11 feet it is difficult to hide outside..

CQ..CQ is the long distance call

For that frequency you do not need license.

Comment: 27 MHz is CB radio, not amateur radio (Ham). CQ is a call to anyone willing to respond; it's not about long distance.

Comment: How are you determining wire length? I see nothing in the question that would indicate the length.

Comment: @manasse maybe because that is the proper length for this sort of antenna? Or perhaps Ruskes was the previous owner and installed the antenna :)

Comment: You can't quite see it in the picture I took, but the red marker says 11 1/4. I assumed it was from building the house, but maybe it's related to the antenna length. I didn't measure, but it certainly seemed longer than 11 feet when I was tracing it around in the ceiling